# Passing props from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass some props from children to parent, and I've found this video on Youtube:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtImABK_VHo
```

I tried to implement that logic (the second approach) and I get some errors. Here's the code:

The way I'm trying to render:

```
<GameAnswers arrayAnswers={['Yes', 'No']} correctAnswer="Yes" />
```

GameAnswers.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './css/GameAnswers.css';

type Answers = {
    arrayAnswers: Array<string>,
    correctAnswer: string
}

function GameAnswers(props: Answers) {
    const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");

    const handleAnswerChange = function (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setSelectedAnswer(e.target.value);
    }

    const determineButtonVariant = function (answer: string) {
        if (answer !== selectedAnswer) {
            return "primary";
        } else if (answer === props.correctAnswer) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "danger";
        }
    }

    return {
        selectedAnswer,
        render: (
            <div className="game-answers">
                <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="answers">
                    {props.arrayAnswers.map(function (answer) {
                        return <ToggleButton
                            id={answer}
                            value={answer}
                            onChange={handleAnswerChange}
                            variant={determineButtonVariant(answer)}
                        >{answer}</ToggleButton>
                    })}
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GameAnswers;
```

The errors:

```
'GameAnswers' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type '{ selectedAnswer: string; render: JSX.Element; }' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type '{ selectedAnswer: string; render: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key  TS2786
```

Is that approach from the video valid? The video is from 1 aug 2021, so it should be, but I get some errors as you can see and I don't really know how to fix them.

If it is, what am I missing?

Comment: dude you are not returning `JSX` from "GameAnswers", instead you are returning an object. `return {
        selectedAnswer,`

Comment: You're not returning valid JSX. `selectedAnswer, render: (...` isn't valid code.

Comment: That's exactly what does he return in that YouTube video and it seems to work for him. Can you check it?

Comment: I'm not going through the whole video. Can you copy the URL using the timestamp function option, and paste it in here, because if he is doing that his code doesn't work either.

Comment: Sure: https://youtu.be/BtImABK_VHo?t=127

Comment: That code is for a hook, not a component. You can tell because React differentiates between functions that start use Pascal case (DoThing), and functions that start with `use`, like default hooks like `useEffect` or bespoke hooks like, I dunno, `useHammer`.

Comment: @Andy got it. So, would you mind showing me what would be the best way to pass props from child to parent for my components, please?

Comment: [Pass a handler function that you declare in your parent](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) to your child in its props, and then call that handler from the child passing in the values you want the parent to know about.

Comment: @Andy I managed to do it. If you want to, you can add your comment as an answer - I will accept it asap.

Comment: That's ok @OctavianNiculescu. I don't think an answer would add any value. I'm just glad I could help.